# cumulative sum in R with conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

The column Signal3 is what I am struggling to code.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1234)
df <- tibble(signal1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
             signal2 = rbinom(31, 1, 0.7), 
             signal3 = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2))
```

Basically, if signal1 == 1, then we start counting how many '1' in rows we have in signal2 (until signal2==0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create groups based on encountering the start or end condition, then on the grouped data return the cumulative sum of `signal2` when the cumulative sum of `signal1` is greater than `0`, else return `0`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(signal1 == 1 | signal2 == 0)) %>%
  mutate(signal3 = ifelse(cumsum(signal1) > 0, cumsum(signal2), 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 31 × 3
   signal1 signal2 signal3
     <dbl>   <int>   <dbl>
 1       0       1       0
 2       0       1       0
 3       1       1       1
 4       0       1       2
 5       0       0       0
 6       0       1       0
 7       0       1       0
 8       0       1       0
 9       0       1       0
10       1       1       1
# … with 21 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: This is such a creative solution!  I would never thought about the 'or' condition in the cumsum in the group_by.  Love it!   Thank you very much for sharing.

Comment: I am voting for this answer for its simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

and imagining `$signal3` starts out life populated by `0s`, using `base R` and a feckless series of `for` loops to progressively collect values needed to further populate `$signal3` one could:

```
set.seed(1234)
df_sig <- structure(list(signal1 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), signal2 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), signal3 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -31L), class = "data.frame")
# i.e. df_sig <- structure(list(...
```

starts of the logic are

```
starts <- which(df_sig$signa1 = 1L)
 starts
[1]  3 10 15 22 30
```

find ends

```
for ( i in 1:length(starts)) {
  ends[i] <- starts[i] + rle(df_sig$signal2[starts[i]:length(df_sig$signal2)])$lengths[1] -1
}
ends
[1]  4 13 15 25 31
```

create sequences

```
counts_seq <- list() # to receive sequences
# a further feckless for loop
for ( i in 1:length(ends)) {
   counts_seq[[i]] <- seq(1, ends[i] - starts[i]+1, 1)
}
counts_seq
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2
```

populate `$signal3`

```
# the last for loop
for (i in 1:length(starts)){
  df_sig$signal3[starts[i]:ends[i]] <- counts_seq[[i]]
}
df_sig
   signal1 signal2 signal3
1        0       1       0
2        0       1       0
3        1       1       1
4        0       0       2
5        0       1       0
6        0       1       0
7        0       1       0
8        0       1       0
9        0       1       0
10       1       0       1
11       0       1       2
12       0       0       3
13       0       1       4
14       0       1       0
15       1       1       1
16       0       1       0
17       0       1       0
18       0       1       0
19       0       0       0
20       0       1       0
21       0       1       0
22       1       1       1
23       0       1       2
24       0       0       3
25       0       1       4
26       0       1       0
27       0       1       0
28       0       0       0
29       0       1       0
30       1       0       1
31       0       1       2
```

which looks like its going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `purrr::accumulate2` to count elements only when the 'gate' state is open `(> 0)`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df |>
    mutate(hi = signal1 & signal2,
           lo = !signal2,
           s3 = accumulate2(hi, lo,
                            \(gate, hi, lo) {
                                if (hi)
                                    1
                                else
                                    if (lo)
                                        0
                                else
                                    if (gate)
                                        gate + 1
                                else
                                    0
                            }, .init = 0)[-1] |>
               unlist())

##>    signal1 signal2 signal3    hi    lo s3
##> 1        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 2        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 3        1       1       1  TRUE FALSE  1
##> 4        0       1       2 FALSE FALSE  2
##> 5        0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 6        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 7        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 8        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 9        0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 10       1       1       1  TRUE FALSE  1
##> 11       0       1       2 FALSE FALSE  2
##> 12       0       1       3 FALSE FALSE  3
##> 13       0       1       4 FALSE FALSE  4
##> 14       0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 15       1       1       1  TRUE FALSE  1
##> 16       0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 17       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 18       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 19       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 20       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 21       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 22       1       1       1  TRUE FALSE  1
##> 23       0       1       2 FALSE FALSE  2
##> 24       0       1       3 FALSE FALSE  3
##> 25       0       1       4 FALSE FALSE  4
##> 26       0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 27       0       1       0 FALSE FALSE  0
##> 28       0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 29       0       0       0 FALSE  TRUE  0
##> 30       1       1       1  TRUE FALSE  1
##> 31       0       1       2 FALSE FALSE  2
```

Comment: Thank you @stefano!  This works as well.   I had a few trials with purrr::map but without success.   I need to check what is accumulate... never used it before.  Always used map or map2.

Comment: `purrr::accumulate` is always useful when you want to keep track of a state. Also `base::Reduce` has this possibility.